# Configuring LAMP Environment in Linux Mint using XAMPP- installing Memcache

Tags: php, linux, unix, memcached, xampp

Okies, I have successfully installed the XAMPP and added virtual hosts and am able to make database calls and stuff. The problem I am facing is while trying to enable the memcache module. 
Currently trying to configure using these links.

1. http://theindexer.wordpress.com/2008/06/02/installing-a-lamp-stack-on-linux-using-xampp-for-linux/
2. http://theindexer.wordpress.com/2008/06/11/installing-xdebug-on-xampp-for-linux/
3. http://lynxbites.blogspot.com/2009/09/steps-to-install-memcache.html

The problem I am facing is while starting the phpize from /opt/lampp/bin/phpize

I am getting the following error.

```
Cannot find config.m4. 
Make sure that you run '/opt/lampp/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module
```

Can any one tell me wat to do for this error and if anyone has any useful links for configuring memcache on linux using XAMPP please paste here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing some packages to install. I solved the phpize problem when tryinng to install xdebug following the following guidelines

http://www.spiration.co.uk/post/1385/Cannot-find-autoconf.-Please-check-your-autoconf-installation

Answer (score 1):

First unzip the xdebug. 
In the step of phpize make sure that you can see the file named (config.m4) by issueing the `(ls) command`, i.e. enter inside the zipped file twice as in

```
~/Downloads/xdebug-2.2.3/xdebug-2.2.3# sudo phpize
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running as root: `sudo phpize...`